# Impossible to unzip packages and install projects

Tags: macos, symfony, composer-php, unzip

I’m not able to install symfony projects anymore. I don’t know when did it start, it might be after an OS update (MacOS). However I always have the same error when I run composer install for many of the packages:

```
Failed to extract sensio/framework-extra-bundle: (2) '/usr/bin/unzip' -qq '/my-project/vendor/composer/tmp-1010d00a3d49fcdd3589312d5d1a82a7.zip' -d '/Users/cflieller/service-bedrock-data-api/vendor/composer/d097aff0'

/my-project/vendor/composer/d097aff0/src/DependencyInjection/SensioFrameworkExtraExtension.php  bad CRC 610d531d  (should be d720d666)
file #25:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  17713
file #26:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  19276
file #27:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  21074
file #28:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  22508
file #29:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  23816

    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
    Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
```

I already tried what I found online:

- `composer clearcache`
- installing homebrew unzip but same problem

EDIT: I tried to install the project using `--prefer-source`. It almost worked except for one package that composer couldn’t get from its git repo.